# Ajax formdata file upload with progress percent

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, ajax

**I got the same code but I'm am getting this kind error:**

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
>   at HTMLInputElement. (upload.js:18)
>   at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)
>   at HTMLInputElement.v.handle (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2)

This is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.upload-btn').on('click', function(){
        $('#upload-input').click();

        $('.progress-bar').text('0%');
        $('.progress-bar').width('0%');
    });

    $('#upload-input').on('change', function(){
        var uploadInput = $('#upload-input').val();

        if(uploadInput != undefined){
        //    var form = $('form')[0];// You need to use standard javascript object here

            var formData = new FormData();
            console.log(uploadInput[0]);
            
            formData.append('upload', uploadInput[0].files[0]).val();

            $.ajax({
                url: '/upload',
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function(data){
                    uploadInput.val('');
                },

                xhr: function(){
                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

                    xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e){
                        if(e.lengthComputable){
                            var uploadPercent = e.loaded / e.total;
                            uploadPercent = (uploadPercent * 100);

                            $('.progress-bar').text(uploadPercent + '%');
                            $('.progress-bar').width(uploadPercent + '%');

                            if(uploadPercent == 100){
                                $('.progress-bar').text('Completed');
                                $('#completed').text('File Uploaded');
                            }
                        }
                    }, false);

                    return xhr;
                }
            })
        }
    })
})
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar"></div>
  </div>   
  <button class="btn btn-success btn-md upload-btn" type="button">Upload File</button>
  <input type="file" class="form-control" name="upload" id="upload-input" style="display: none;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code have many errors

```
var uploadInput = $('#upload-input').val();
```

1. You are selecting file path, not `<input>` tag change it: `var uploadInput = $('#upload-input');`
2. This is wrong Syntex `formData.append('upload', uploadInput[0].files[0]).val();`
   Change it: `formData.append('upload', uploadInput[0].files[0]);`

Working code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.upload-btn').on('click', function(){
        $('#upload-input').click();

        $('.progress-bar').text('0%');
        $('.progress-bar').width('0%');
    });

    $('#upload-input').on('change', function(){
        var uploadInput = $('#upload-input');

        if(uploadInput != undefined){
        //    var form = $('form')[0];// You need to use standard javascript object here

            var formData = new FormData();
            console.log(uploadInput[0]);

            formData.append('upload', uploadInput[0].files[0]);

            $.ajax({
                url: '/upload',
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function(data){
                    uploadInput.val('');
                },

                xhr: function(){
                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

                    xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e){
                        if(e.lengthComputable){
                            var uploadPercent = e.loaded / e.total;
                            uploadPercent = (uploadPercent * 100);

                            $('.progress-bar').text(uploadPercent + '%');
                            $('.progress-bar').width(uploadPercent + '%');

                            if(uploadPercent == 100){
                                $('.progress-bar').text('Completed');
                                $('#completed').text('File Uploaded');
                            }
                        }
                    }, false);

                    return xhr;
                }
            })
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: I tried that already but it won't work last time but now it's working fine. Thank you so much!